# Google One Tap is causing a Layout shift (>0.1) on mobile

Tags: google-signin, core-web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift

I have used the chrome profiler to identify the Layout shifts on our website and discovered that the Google One Tap banner is causing a significant layout shift (> 0.1) on mobile ([Image of profiler showing layout shift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rVDE.png)). I have also added a Performance Observer using [layout-instability](https://github.com/WICG/layout-instability) API to identify the component causing the CLS, and it also indicated the same.

I have tried changing the position of the one-tap using `data-prompt_parent_id`, but this is ignored on mobile web browsers as mentioned in the [developers guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/change-position).

Answer (score 0):

You might try to re-test, recent improvements have been made to reduce or eliminate layout shift and improve the CLS score for Core Web Vitals.